# Htaccess não valida corretamente a regra de redirecionamento

Tags: php, regex, htaccess

Possui em *htaccess* no qual a *regex* funciona perfeitamente sem números na regra, mas com números não funciona corretamente.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-to-([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30})\/?$ page.php?ti=$1&at=$2&pl=$3 [NC,L]//linha anterior
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-to-([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30})-([0-9]{1,3})\/?$ page.php?ti=$1&at=$2&pl=$3&pagination=$4 [NC,L]
```

A linha anterior é a pagina e a segunda linha a pagina com paginação. se a terceira regra, tanto na primeira como na segunda linha, for `a-zA-Z-` (com o tracinho no final mesmo) tudo funciona beleza, mas se for `a-zA-Z0-9-` não funciona como deveria.

a URL da pagina é algo assim:

```
www.exemplo.com/bla-to-ble-nome-com-numero-2
```

url da pagina com paginação

```
www.exemplo.com/bla-to-ble-nome-com-numero-2-3
```

`nome-com-numero-2` é referente a parte 3 do regex

Answer (score 1):

A razão é que ele não esta caindo na regra 2 e sim na regra 1.

Veja bem `([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30})` este trecho contempla exatamente `nome-com-numero-2-3`

Para solucionar este problema você deve alterar a ordem da regra, pois assim você parte do mais especifico, para o menos especifico.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-to-([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30})-([0-9]{1,3})\/?$ page.php?ti=$1&at=$2&pl=$3&pagination=$4 [NC,L] // regra mais especifica
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-to-([a-zA-Z]{1,20})-([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30})\/?$ page.php?ti=$1&at=$2&pl=$3 [NC,L]// regra menos especifica
```

Comment: Obrigada @GuilhermeLautert, desta forma o mais especifico esta funcionando, já o menos especifico (sem a paginação) não aparece nenhum erro, mas os campos ficam vazios (gets que buscam os valores na url)

Comment: @Gisele agora to sem tempo para desenvolver a solução, mas a razão é que mesmo alterando a ordem o mais especifico também contempla a *string* menor, teria de refatorar a REGEX.